# How to Change the Fill Value of a Background Image SVG Dynamically From CMS

Tags: html, css, svg, sass, content-management-system

I have a button on a page where the content reads something like this "I am a button >" The side carrot symbol in the button is set as a SVG background image in an :after pseudo class from the class on that button.

I would like the content editors to be able to change the color of the text and the SVG via a HEX color picker in the CMS. Based on their selection, I'm currently appending style tag to the button.

I can change the text color no problem but I'm stuck in trying to figure out a way to change the SVG fill color, based on their selection  / updates to the  style tag.

I'd like to either be able to adjust the color directly with the style tag or somehow pass the HEX value into my SASS mixin. Is there a way to do that? Also open to other ideas (ideally CSS only) to accomplish this. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn" style="color: #E47B8E">I am a button</a>
```

SASS:

```
@mixin btn($bgColor: $stdBlue, $radius: 5px, $borColor: transparent, $display: inline-flex, $padding: 15px 40px, $fontSize: 0.88em, $weight: normal, $decorate: none, $color: white, $transform: uppercase, $borderStyle: solid) { 
      background-color: $bgColor;
      border-radius: $radius;
      border-color: $borColor;
      display: $display;
      padding: $padding;
      font-size: $fontSize;
      font-weight: $weight;
      border-style: $borderStyle;
      text-decoration: $decorate;
      color: $color;
      text-transform: $transform;

      &:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      &:after {
        content: '';
        background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 6.799 10.477"><path data-name="Path 226" d="M6.8 5.238l-5.24 5.238L0 8.916l3.678-3.678L0 1.56 1.56 0z" fill="#fff"/></svg>');
        width: 7px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        margin-left: 5px;
      }
    }

.btn {
    @include btn;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up going a different route here and, rather than placing the SVG via a background image or content in CSS, I implemented it via HTML and set fill="currentColor." currenColor enables the SVG to inherit the color of the text in the button, as set in the CCMS. Code is below (in the form of a Twig Macro on Craft CMS). Code for setting the color of the button that the SVG inherits is in a separate template into which the macro is included.

```
{% macro button(url, text, options={}) %}

  {% set svg %}
    <svg class="btn__arrow" width="7px" height="20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 6.799 10.477"><path data-name="Path 226" d="M6.8 5.238l-5.24 5.238L0 8.916l3.678-3.678L0 1.56 1.56 0z" fill="currentColor"/></svg>
  {% endset %}

  {% set options = {
      target:'',
      classes:'btn',
      id:'',
      type:'',
      buttonStyle:'',
      linkStyle: '',
      svg: svg,
    } | merge(options) %}

  {% if options.type %}   
    <button {% if options.classes %}class="{{ options.classes }}"{% endif %} {% if options.id %}id="{{ options.id }}"{% endif %} {% if options.buttonStyle %}style="{{ options.buttonStyle }}"{% endif %} type="{{ options.type }}">{{ text | raw }} {% if options.svg | length %}{{ options.svg }}{% endif %}</button>
  {% else %}
    <a href="{{ url }}" {% if options.target %}target="{{ options.target }}"{% endif %} {% if options.classes %}class="{{ options.classes }}"{% endif %} {% if options.id %}id="{{ options.id }}"{% endif %} {% if options.buttonStyle %}style="{{ options.buttonStyle }}"{% endif %} {% if options.linkStyle %} style="{{ options.linkStyle }}"{% endif %}>{{ text | raw }} {% if options.svg | length %}{{ options.svg }}{% endif %}</a>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `url(yourSVGdata)` as the `content` instead. I THINK that should allow you to target the SVG with css. You cannot target an SVG with CSS if it is an external file or if it is a background image.